# Repeatable background creates gap on top

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is the result I am getting, I made the middle part of the background repeatable so when I add text it stretches vertically, but for some reason when I add text it creates a gap between the top part and the middle part.

```css
.resumetop {
    background: no-repeat;
    width: 1178px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/resume_top.jpg");
}
.resumemiddle {
    background: no-repeat;
    width: 1178px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/resume_middle.jpg");
}
.resumebottom {
    background: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("images/resume_bottom.jpg");
    width: 1178px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resumetop">
</div>
<div class="resumemiddle">
    <p class="resumetext">
        dksjfgjhsfguysdg
    </p>
</div>
<div class="resumebottom">

</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably have top margin on your `p` tags. Impossible to tell without a [MCVE]

Comment: "I made the middle part of the background repeatable" - but you've set `background: no-repeat` on every class here.

Comment: The No-repeat bit is to prevent the image from tiling horizontally, the height: 100% value is what allows the middle section to stretch vertically when I add text.

Comment: Please give us some example images or upload your images to imgur or something so that you can use absolute URLs that we can see take effect.

Comment: An approach using the `border-image` style might be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by your p tags.

Either try:

```
p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

Or if you want to avoid such problems completely, try:

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

This takes away all default margins and paddings.

Ps. please next time, add an img url that works for everyone, not something that's stored locally.

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.resumetop {
    background: no-repeat;
    width: 1178px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/11551/images/hero_full/Bernard_de_wetter_wwf_canon_113974.jpg?1462218465");
}
.resumemiddle {
    background: no-repeat;
    width: 1178px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/11551/images/hero_full/Bernard_de_wetter_wwf_canon_113974.jpg?1462218465");
}
.resumebottom {
    background: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/11551/images/hero_full/Bernard_de_wetter_wwf_canon_113974.jpg?1462218465");
    width: 1178px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resumetop">
</div>
<div class="resumemiddle">
    <p class="resumetext">
        dksjfgjhsfguysdg
    </p>
</div>
<div class="resumebottom">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the margin and padding seems to have fixed my problem!